# Install Qt 5.5 Instead of 5.8 on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I'm installing Qt as a dependency for a program but anything above 5.5 won't work because of a webkit issue.

I can't install it with pacman as it will only install the latest version 5.8. How do I install the program directly?

Comment: You don't: Arch is a rolling release, you get the latest stable versions.

Comment: @jasonwryan so I would uninstall via pacman and then install from some other source I guess?

Comment: I would suggest keeping the existing pacman Qt 5.8 as is  and installing Qt 5.5 in a different directory like `/opt/qt5.5/`. Usually, you can specify that with a `--prefix` or similar option while installing. The reason is mainly to not break any dependencies that other Arch packages have on Qt 5.8.